# Using conditional face selection to select by normal

Tags: meshlab

I am trying to select faces by the criteria: "Normals in the Z direction", but only those facing either up or down. The objects are all manifold cubic shapes, with a typical orientation (flat on the ground), not rotated, and the normals are all correctly oriented to the outside.

Using Conditional Face Selection and the boolean (fnz == 1) I am able to select Z-facing normals (both up and down), but I don't know how to limit that selection to normals that just face either up or down. Any help with this would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the precise case you are asking (axis aligned cubic shapes), the expression `(fnz==1)` should only select faces in one orientation, while the expression `(fnz==-1)` should select in the opposite orientation.

If you want to select faces in both orientations, you should use any of these:

```
(fnz==1) || (fnz==-1)
```

or

```
abs(fnz)==1
```

My advise is to use some kind of tolerance in the expression, so it will work with meshes where noise of roundoff errors may have affected the coordinates of the vertices, so I would recommend:

```
fnz>0.9
```

Comment: This answer made me realize I oversimplified my question.
My mesh is an imported Collada model. The import comes in as "double faces", so the front-face is a mesh face and the back-face is a separate mesh face.
To solve this I did the following:

 1. Filters, cleaning and repair > remove duplicate vertices
 2. Filters, cleaning and repair > remove duplicate faces
 3. Filters, normals, curvature and orientation > re-orient coherently
 4. Filters, normals, curvature and orientation > invert faces
    orientation
After this, conditional face selection works as expected. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this answer made me realize I oversimplified my question.
The mesh I have is an imported Collada model. The imported shapes are imported as "double faces", so the front-face is a mesh face and the back-face is a separate mesh face.
To solve this I did the following:

```
 1. Filters, cleaning and repair > remove duplicate vertices
 2. Filters, cleaning and repair > remove duplicate faces
 3. Filters, normals, curvature and orientation > re-orient coherently
 4. Filters, normals, curvature and orientation > invert faces
    orientation
```

After this, conditional face selection worked as expected. Thank you for the help :)